¿Cómo ejecuto un programa desde un menú?
He hecho algunos programas en python y un menú de barra y quiero poner esos programas a ejecutarlos desde el menú pero no sé cómo: no sé la sintaxis o qué se pone en el command.
Lo otro es cómo hacer para que el menú no desaparezca, que los programas corran encima de él y cuando termine y se destruya la ventana quede el programa de menú abajo.
En videos y tutoriales solo dan cómo se crean los menús pero no cómo darle la funcionalidad que necesito.
self.ctasxcob=Menu(self.menuPrincipal,tearoff=0)

    self.ctasxcob.add_command(label="Movimientos",font=15, background = colorbarmen, foreground="white")
    self.ctasxcob.add_separator(background = colorbarmen)
    self.ctasxcob.add_command(label="Estados de cuenta",font=15, background = colorbarmen, foreground="white")
    self.ctasxcob.add_command(label="analisis antiguedad detallado",font=15, background = colorbarmen, foreground="white")
    self.ctasxcob.add_command(label="analisis antiguedad resumido",font=15, background = colorbarmen, foreground="white")
    self.ctasxcob.add_separator(background = colorbarmen)
    self.ctasxcob.add_command(label="Carga de Clientes",font=15, background = colorbarmen, foreground="white")
    self.ctasxcob.add_command(label="Carga Tipo Clientes",font=15, background = colorbarmen, foreground="white")
    self.ctasxcob.add_command(label="Carga de Cobradores",font=15, background = colorbarmen, foreground="white")
    self.ctasxcob.add_command(label="Carga de Sector",font=15, background = colorbarmen, foreground="white")
    self.ctasxcob.add_command(label="Carga de Ciudades",font=15, background = colorbarmen, foreground="white")
    self.ctasxcob.add_command(label="Carga de Estados",font=15, background = colorbarmen, foreground="white")
    self.ctasxcob.add_separator(background = colorbarmen)


Bienvenido. Tienes algún ejemplo de lo que quieres? Y qué intentaste? Es decir, muestra el código

alli pase la parte del codigo que quiero anexar lo dems es lo mismo pero de otros modulos o bueno, sub menus

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

ya lo resolvi habia que crear una funcion con el metodo subprocess.run, y en command poner un lambda para enviarle el nombrre del programa a ejecutar, asi utilizo la misma funcion para todas las opciones que ejecuten programas, muchas gracias y disculpen si no supe expresarme o formular la pregunta

El formato del sitio es de preguntas y respuestas. Pon como respuesta lo que has mencionado, en base a [answer], y acepta tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

ya lo resolvi habia que crear una funcion con el metodo subprocess.run, y en command poner un lambda para enviarle el nombrre del programa a ejecutar, asi utilizo la misma funcion para todas las opciones que ejecuten programas, muchas gracias y disculpen si no supe expresarme o formular la pregunta
